# flutter build apk --split-per-abi: what is the difference between app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk and app.apk

Tags: android, flutter, apk

When I run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` I get 4 files in the directory `flutter-apk`:

1. app-arm64-v8a-release.apk,
2. app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk,
3. app-x86_64.apk,
4. app.apk.

I already know that the first three apks are due to different cpu-architectures/ instructionsets.
On my android-phone I am able to install app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk **and** **app.apk**. So are they the same? Where is the difference?

Comment: How did you get the `app.apk`? Per [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk) there are only 3 APK results: `[project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk`, `[project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk` and `[project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk`. Could you provide a screenshot of result after running `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you first run **flutter build apk** that generates the apk **app.apk**, this apk will run almost to all architectures (decides by itself). Then you again run the command **flutter build apk --split-per-abi**. which means you get the two command results both. Just try to delete all apk output files and re-run the command **flutter build apk --split-per-abi**, I hope you will get only three files.

Answer (score 1):

**app.apk**

> it's a universal APK that contains code for all available instruction
> sets (**armeabi-v7a**, **arm64-v8a**, and **x86_64**). This means that
> the app can run on any device regardless of its CPU architecture.but
> of course it will increase the file size of your app and reduce optimisation

**app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk**

> it's specifically built for devices with the **armeabi-v7a** CPU
> architecture. This APK is optimized to run more efficiently on devices
> with this architecture. The other two APK files
> (**app-arm64-v8a-release.apk and app-x86_64.apk**) are also optimized for> their respective CPU architectures.

**when to use split command ?**

it's pretty straight forward when you are unaware about your device architecture simply build the apk with flutter build apk otherwise use splite command

Answer (score 0):

My search for an answer to the same question as yours ended without a satisfactory result.

Then I came up with the idea of using SHA-256 checksums for file equality verification.

> If you know the checksum of the original file, you can run a checksum or hashing utility on it. If the resulting checksum matches, you know the file you have is identical.
> [[from here]](https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/spectrum/ProductUpdateSummary/ProductUpdateSummary/source/about_sha256.html)

We can see from the hashing results that file **`app.apk` is equal to file `app-armeabi-v7a-staging-release.apk`** based on the hashing of all of the apks.

```
  13:10:25  qrcode_keeper  master  +1 ~1  ﮫ 39ms                             Path
➜ Get-FileHash build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk                                   ----
                                                                                       C:...
Algorithm       Hash
---------       ----
SHA256          4349EF321BDE25DB32FED4D3C8E0BB265BF5BF6595767F20C2D43B8BBD5BDF13      


  13:10:26  qrcode_keeper  master  +1 ~1  ﮫ 80ms                             Path
➜ Get-FileHash build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-staging-release.apk       ----
                                                                                       C:...
Algorithm       Hash
---------       ----
SHA256          4349EF321BDE25DB32FED4D3C8E0BB265BF5BF6595767F20C2D43B8BBD5BDF13      


  13:10:31  qrcode_keeper  master  +1 ~1  ﮫ 72ms                             Path
➜ Get-FileHash build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-arm64-v8a-staging-release.apk         ----
                                                                                       C:...
Algorithm       Hash
---------       ----
SHA256          AE4DDBBCFDD5A0AF273DDBE2A1CF4C56513D63C1D5A2F151EF973855FA190E0B      


  13:10:38  qrcode_keeper  master  +1 ~1  ﮫ 82ms 
➜ Get-FileHash build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-x86_64-staging-release.apk           

Algorithm       Hash
---------       ----
SHA256          1D6EBAAA82DF6984C352E4B06D0300386A26EF19A7DE4CB476105060FC74938B
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [flutter GitHub repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119559):

> When running a flutter app in debug mode, the dart code is compiled just of time (JIT), making it possible to use features like hot reload/restart. In release mode, the code is compiled ahead of time (AOT) to native code. This mode is better for performances and results into a smaller app; it also removes stuffs that are only using in development mode.
> The app-debug.apk file is just the build you get when running/compiling your app in debug mode.

> app.apk -> AOT
>
> app-debug.apk -> JIT

> When you build your app using --split-per-abi param, it results into 3 separated files as mentionned in the docs, located it PROJECT_SRC/build/app/outputs/apk/prod/release/. These files are the optimized build for each android architecture

---

As mentioned from the answer you can see that the difference is the used compilation concept (if you want to read more about it I think [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/just-in-time-jit-and-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation-in-angular-8529f1d6fa9d) is a good start).

I'd assume that `app.apk` and `app-debug.apk` are then used to be furthermore optimized for their specific target platform and are therefore kept as a neccessary side product. I don't think there is any particular reason otherwise to keep those.